# How to bind html code with ng-... attributes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create `<select ng-model='selected' ng-options='stage as stage.name for stage in stages'></select>` element in variable as a string. As you see here, there are ng-... attributes inside the select element. If I use select element without ng-... attribute it is displaying without problem. If I use ng-... inside it, it's not showing anything. So, how do I make it display with ng-...? Please help.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/myScripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div ng-bind-html="htmlCode">
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.stages =
        [{ name: "Identification of Discontinuing Factors", value: 1 },
        { name: "Project Level Assessment", value: 2 },
        { name: "Organizational Readiness Assessment", value: 3 }];

    $scope.htmlCode = "<select ng-model='selectedStage' ng-options='stage as stage.name for stage in stages'></select>";
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to recompile the dom in order to work the `ng-` attributes. use this directive as an attribute to the `ng-bind-html` element.

```
.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope","$sce", function ($scope,$sce) {

    $scope.stages =
        [{ name: "Identification of Discontinuing Factors", value: 1 },
        { name: "Project Level Assessment", value: 2 },
        { name: "Organizational Readiness Assessment", value: 3 }];

    $scope.htmlCode = "<select ng-model='selectedStage' ng-options='stage as stage.name for stage in stages'></select>";
    
    $scope.trust = function(html){
       return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
    }
}]);

app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div ng-bind-html="trust(htmlCode)" dynamic>
       </div>
       
       {{selectedStage}}
    </div>
```